# How to implement stroke width algorithm or is there any practicle implementation available for it in java or javacv?

Tags: java, computer-vision, neural-network, ocr, javacv

I searches many blogs but I am unable to find exact solution for stroke width algorithm.

I am using Neural Network Technique for text recognition from image.

But during image processing it was needed to clean image background for text recognition by Neural Network so during that process distortion in image text araises so result drops sharply.

So prevent this I found http://rnd.azoft.com/algorithm-identifying-barely-legible-embossed-text-image/ site.But I faces difficulty in stroke width algorithm implementation.
And also did not find stroke width algorithm.

Comment: Take a look at this paper: http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=149305, and you can find some implementation of the algorithm at https://sites.google.com/site/roboticssaurav/strokewidthnokia

Comment: but here,I can't find that algorithm